# componentWillMount function in React Native Navigation

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am new in Ract Native and I am trying to build a small app using react native navigation.

I can see in the movie-app example provided on their site (react native navigation) that they do not use a componentWillMount function in app.js, but they have a startApp() function instead, called in the constructor.

I am basically trying to define the firebase configuration in the componentWillMounth function, but a simple console log shows that the function is somehow never run.

I would like to set up the app properly, for best performance, so I am wondering if using the startApp function is basically the same, no need to use a componentWillMount function?

Update: Code below

**index.ios.js**

`import App from './src/app';
const app = new App();`

**app.js**

```
import ...

class App extends Component {
    state = {
      loggedIn: null
    }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.startApp();
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('COMPONENT WILL MOUNT');
    // Initialize Firebase
    const config = {
      ...
      ...
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }


  startApp() {
    console.log('START APP');

    // Initialize Firebase here???




const tabs = [
     ...
];

  if (this.state.loggedIn) {
    Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
      tabs,
      tabsStyle: {
        ...
      }
    });
  } else {
    Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
      ...
    });
  }
  } // startApp
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of your code, otherwise it is hard to figure out the exact problem. Also, you wrote 'componentWillMounth'. Check that the same typo is not in the code, because if it is, that is the reason why it is not being called.

Comment: Hi @martinarroyo, there's not much going on right now, I am only trying to find out where's the best place to initialize the firebase configuration.
Anyway, I added some simplifed code to make it more clear, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your componentWillMount is not being executed because you are not using your component within the React render lifecycle (you are instantiating it not in a `render`, but with `new`, which will only run the constructor of the component. Move it to your index render method, like this:

```
class EntryPoint extends React.Component {
  render(){
    <App />
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', ()=>EntryPoint);
```

Comment: Thanks @martinarroyo. Unfortunately, this solution is not working. Doesn't return an error but nothing is displayed on screen. I also added the missing return() part but no luck.  I am wondering if the solution I am currently using is totally wrong, or if it's "just another way of doing it"?

Comment: Maybe you have some minor mistake in your code, if you post your complete JS file we might be able to spot it.